# autoit not works from php silenum

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I need to auth to proxy with selenium on Windows 7 with cygwin64. I try use AuthIt to login to my proxy.

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$c = array(
    WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox',  
    WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY => array(
        'proxyType' => 'manual',  
        'httpProxy' => 'my.proxy.net:80'));  

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $c);

//LOOKS LIKE IT FREEZE HERE FOR 30 seconds!
// and is not going to go to 'exec'
$driver->get("http://www.whatismyip.com/");

$r = exec('../../bin/proxy_auth.exe', $a, $b);
```

where proxy_auth.exe is converted AutoIt script

```
WinWait("Authentication Required","",30)
WinActivate ("Authentication Required")
If WinExists("Authentication Required") Then
  Send("log{TAB}")
  Send("pwd{Enter}")
EndIf
```

If I run AutoIt scripts as standalone -- all works fine. But in php script it does not find window.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with windows manipulation you want to set these options:

```
#RequireAdmin Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ; 1=search children also
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4) ; 4=advanced
Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 1) ; 1=do detect
```

Also *Send()* will send the keypress to any active window. The safe way to do this is:

```
ControlSend ( "title", "text", controlID, "string" [, flag = 0] )
```